# Getting a flash slideshow to play automatically

Tags: html, flash

So I just embedded code for a slideshow from Flickr onto the front page of our library website.  I apologize in advance for knowing practically nothing about html.  I used a website that generated the html for me.  The slideshow looks good and is functioning correctly.  However, you currently have to push the "play" button in order for the slideshow to begin.  What do I need to change in the code to cause it to begin playing automatically when a person first visits the site?  Here is the code generated by flickr slideshow:

```
<div style="width:400px;height:400px; padding-bottom:10px; text-align:center;margin:auto;" ><object width="500" height="500" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"  codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"> <param name="flashvars" value="offsite=true&amp;lang=en-us&amp;page_show_url=%2Fphotos%2Fmoorelibrary%2Fshow&amp;page_show_back_url=%2Fphotos%2Fmoorelibrary%2F&amp;user_id=10214752@N03" /> <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /> <param name="src" value="https://www.flickr.com/apps/slideshow/show.swf?v=71649" /> <embed width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="https://www.flickr.com/apps/slideshow/show.swf?v=71649" flashvars="offsite=true&amp;lang=en-us&amp;page_show_url=%2Fphotos%2Fmoorelibrary%2Fshow&amp;page_show_back_url=%2Fphotos%2Fmoorelibrary%2F&amp;user_id=10214752@N03" allowFullScreen="true" /> </object><br /><small>Created with <a href="http://www.flickrslideshow.com">flickr slideshow</a>.</small></div>
```

*Edit* This website is mangling my code formatting and I'm not sure how to prevent it from doing that.

Answer (score 1):

The flickr slideshow that you are using, doesn't has the option.

Try this first: http://www.flickrembed.com

Or this http://www.slideflickr.com/create/

In speed tab you can see the option "start paused", so dont check it!

Comment: Well, I tried this method and I just keep getting an "unknown error" message on the preview screen so I'm not sure it will work for me.

Comment: @Lesley Ragsdale where can I get an album for test?

Comment: @RamonSchmidtRocha understand that new (low rep) accounts cannot upvote useful answers. Silly system.

Comment: @LesleyRagsdale try to show a link to your issue in action

Comment: @LesleyRagsdale I found this: https://flickrembed.com/  check! Use theme slider and vincule your configurations. I only test with Instagram tag and it works